# How do I replace dataframe values in R based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, multiple-columns

If I have a dataframe with the following columns with the following elements

```
    w x y z
    0 0 1 2
    0 0 3 4
    0 0 5 6
```

How do I change the values of non-zero columns without calling the columns directly?

For example, If I want to update the nonzero values by multiplying by 10

```
    w x  y z
    0 0 10 20
    0 0 30 40
    0 0 50 60
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Can you state the replacement rule and show expected output in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply each cell by 10 (0 is still 0 then ;-)

```
df <- read.table(text =
"w x y z
0 0 1 2
0 0 3 4
0 0 5 6", sep = " ", header = T)
df
df = df * 10
```

Result:

```
  w x  y  z
1 0 0 10 20
2 0 0 30 40
3 0 0 50 60
```

**Generalized solution:** To ignore any value of choice (or even a more complex filter expression) you can select only the cells which do not have this value and update them:

```
df[df != 1] <- df[df != 1] * 10
```

Result:

```
  w x  y  z
1 0 0  1 20
2 0 0 30 40
3 0 0 50 60
```

Note: If you don't use the `,` in square brackets of a `data.frame` the expression is applied to all cells that match this criteria...

Comment: yes, did it in parallel (at least I a provide a minimal reproducible example). No need to upvote my answer anyhow :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can subset the part of the data frame you want using `[`, and calculate the replacement values in the same way:

```
> df <- data.frame(w = c(0,0,0), x = c(0,0,0), y = c(1,3,5), z = c(2,4,6))
> df[df != 0] <- df[df != 0] * 10
> df
  w x  y  z
1 0 0 10 20
2 0 0 30 40
3 0 0 50 60
```

Although if you are actually just multiplying by 10, you can do `df <- df * 10` for the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you can simply multiply per 10 :)

```
 plouf
  w x y z
1 0 0 1 2
2 0 0 3 4
3 0 0 5 6
 plouf*10
  w x  y  z
1 0 0 10 20
2 0 0 30 40
3 0 0 50 60
```